# How to define a loss or win between two positions

Tags: pine-script

In this code, how can I register a postion Golong that is stopped at "X", mark as a profit or loss?
I need to define this, to be able to use it as a filter, to show only the Golong or Goshort labels after the previous position was a loss.
The X is a particular position after the Golong or Goshort signal, to stop that position. The X happens at the crossover from price with the previous week high or low (low for Golong signal, high for Goshort signal). My problem is how to define the win or loss for that particular position of an X compared to the position of the proceeding Golong or Goshort position.

[image: win or loss ?]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at    https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=4
//By Juros

study(title="Universal weekly breakout + universal filter", shorttitle="weekly breakout+  filter", overlay=true, precision=8)
prevwkH = input(true, title="Show previous week high?")
prevwkL = input(true, title="show previous week low?")

//previous week high and low
prevWeekHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevWeekLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1], lookahead=true)

//previous Week high and low Plots
plot(prevwkH and prevWeekHigh ? prevWeekHigh : na, title="Prev Week High", style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)
plot(prevwkL and prevWeekLow ? prevWeekLow : na, title="Prev Week Low", style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// stop location for short and long position (at crossover of previous week low or high)
Stopshort = crossover (high, prevWeekHigh)
Stoplong = crossunder (low, prevWeekLow)

Longposmemo = false
Longposmemo := Stopshort ? true : Stoplong ? false : Longposmemo[1]

Longcond = Stopshort and not Longposmemo[1]
color_1 = color.new(color.green, 70)


Shortposmemo = false
Shortposmemo := Stoplong ? true : Stopshort ? false : Shortposmemo[1]

Shortcond = Stoplong and not Shortposmemo[1]
color_2 = color.new(color.red, 70)
//bgcolor(Sellnow ? color_2 : na)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Signal for long and short
Golong = false 
Golong := high > prevWeekHigh and Longcond[1]

Goshort = false
Goshort := low < prevWeekLow and Shortcond[1]


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// plots : X where the position is stopped
plotchar (Longcond, char='X', location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow)
plotchar (Shortcond, char='X', location=location.belowbar, color=color.yellow)


plotshape (Golong ? high : na, style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar,   color=color.lime, size=size.tiny, text = 'GOLONG', textcolor=color.black)
plotshape (Goshort ? low : na, style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color=color.fuchsia, size=size.tiny, text ='GOSHORT', textcolor=color.black)

// alerts
alertcondition(Golong, title="Weakly breakout go long", message="WBO go long")
alertcondition(Goshort, title="weakly breakout go short", message="WBO go short")

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Filter to show only those signals that follow on the previous position (long or short) that was a loss
```